# How to show button when the user clicks a listbox item?

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, triggers, styles

I was checking this window. It has a listbox, and when you click an item, it shows three buttons.

I want to implement something similar in my program. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind to the `IsSelected` of the item, either by directly binding the `Visibility` using a [`BooleanToVisibilityConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx) or by employing a [`DataTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx).

1. Direct Binding

   ```xml
   <ListBox.Resources>
       <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="b2v"/>
   </ListBox.Resources>
   ```

   ```xml
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <!-- ... -->
           <Button Visibility="{Binding IsSelected,
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem},
                                        Converter={StaticResource b2v}}".../>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   ```
2. Style & DataTrigger

   ```
   throw new NotImplementedException();
   ```